# There is a way to hide slider's (ipywidgets) value?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I want to hide the value next this [slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XevWG.png). Any way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `readout=False` when instantiating your widgets.

```py
from ipywidgets import IntSlider
IntSlider(readout=False)
```

[image]

Comment: That was exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: How can I do this? I gave you a positive vote, but I have a reputation <15, so it doesn't show you...

Comment: There should be a grey tick mark beneath the voting arrows, click it and it should turn green. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235